# How to Send Events with IEventBroker

Tags: eclipse-plugin, e4

Simple question: I'm evaluating E4 yet again, and want to send a simple event with the `IEventBroker`. Multiple tutorials state that's the way to go:

```
@Inject
private IEventBroker eventBroker;

this.eventBroker.send("org.acme.event", myEventObject);
```

However all of the fail to acknowledge how to register "org.acme.event" as a topic, so I won't get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid topic: org.acme.event
at org.osgi.service.event.Event.validateTopicName(Event.java:236)
at org.osgi.service.event.Event.<init>(Event.java:78)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.constructEvent(EventBroker.java:153)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:79)
```

What is the complete way to send events using the `IEventBroker`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to register event topics.

Event topic names are defined by the OSGi specification (`IEventBroker` is a simplified interface to the OSGI `EventAdmin`).

The problem here is that only 'A-Z', 'a-z', '0-9', '_', and '-' are allowed in the parts of the topic name. Parts are separated using '/' not '.'. So 'org/acme/event' would be OK.